# How do I hook a django-allauth signal?

Tags: django, signals, django-allauth

Signals page for django-allauth: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

I am trying to hook the email_verified signal:

`allauth.account.signals.email_confirmed(request, email_address)`

And am getting nothing whenever a user confirms their email. Here is my code:

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from channels import Group

def send_to_user_socket(sender, **kwargs):
    Group('%s.get-started' % (kwargs['request'].user.username)).send({'text': json.dumps({'message': 'Email confirmed'})})

email_confirmed.connect(send_to_user_socket)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: here is my apps.py code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class EngineConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'engine'

    def ready(self):
        import engine.signals
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the signal is attached by printing something out to the console (or dropping into a pdb breakpoint), to ensure it's not something that channels is just dropping?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm new to signals and I think I set up the signal wrong. Does my code look valid? I did the `Group` command in `python manage.py shell` and it worked fine

Comment: There are a couple of ways to set up signals: I generally use the @receiver decorator, as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver, but your code appears valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it was resolved by doing the following

In your **init**.py file within the particular app, add

default_app_config = "{enter_you_app_name}.apps.{Appname}Config"

eg

```
default_app_config = "authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig"
```

also import

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@reciever(enter_the_correct_details)
def send_to_user_socket(sender, **kwargs):
    Group('%s.get-started' % (kwargs['request'].user.username)).send({'text': json.dumps({'message': 'Email confirmed'})})

email_confirmed.connect(send_to_user_socket)
```