# django-allauth signals user_signed_in signal isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-signals

I am relatively new to django, and trying to trigger a function on login. I have tested the function itself, and it works fine. The django-allauth login is also correctly configured. However, i cannot seem to trigger the signal below on login.

See code below... Any help would be appreciated...

**pages/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PagesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pages'

    def ready(self):
        import apps.pages.signals
```

**pages/signals.py**

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from .models import Token

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_(request, user, **kwargs):
    is_valid = Token.objects.filter(valid_until__gte=timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(seconds=10800)).values()
    if not is_valid:
        new = Token(token='valid', valid_until=timezone.now())
    else:
        new = Token(token='not valid', valid_until=timezone.now())
    
    new.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this after much digging online...

You need to use the full python path to the application. This needs to be consistent with in settings.py, apps.py and **init**.py i.e.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['dir.appname',]
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dir.appname'

    def ready(self):
        import dir.appname.signals
```

****init**.py**

```
default_app_config = 'dir.appname.apps.AppnameConfig'
```

This following articles were useful in helping resolve the issue -

[Django : Can't import 'module'. Check that module AppConfig.name is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177499/django-cant-import-module-check-that-module-appconfig-name-is-correct)

[How do I hook a django-allauth signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509224/how-do-i-hook-a-django-allauth-signal)